# Unity C# - Сhanging the horizontal position does not work correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote the following code for my runner, it is responsible for moving between 3 lines horizontally and the code works, however, if you rotate the character along the Y axis by 90 degrees to the left or right, then everything breaks

```
Vector3 targetPosition = _cachedTransform.position.z * _cachedTransform.forward +
                         _cachedTransform.position.y * _cachedTransform.up;

switch (_desiredLine)
{
    case 0:
        targetPosition += Vector3.left * _lineDistance;
        break;
    case 2:
        targetPosition += Vector3.right * _lineDistance;
        break;
}

targetPosition = Vector3.Lerp(_cachedTransform.position, targetPosition, _lineBlendSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
_rigidbody.MovePosition(targetPosition);
```

I tried using TransformDirection but it didn't help

Comment: `targetPosition += _cachedTransform.right * _lineDistance;` ?

Answer (score 0):

`targetPosition += _cachedTransform.right * _lineDistance;`